# Installation problem with XY Tools

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Pyton libs for XYtools to read Excel files](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31314/how-to-install-pyton-libs-for-xytools-to-read-excel-files)

I was using XY Tools plug-in for QGIS that converts Excel files into attribute table and shape files etc, but once I select the file for conversion this appears:

*There is a problem with loading a python module which is needed to read/write Excel files. Please see documentation/help how to install python xlw and xlrd libraries.*

What should I do?